# Match two alternative or either both words with regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

in Java I need to find a regex able to match sentences like :

```
"John Smith wants a dog and a cat"

"John wants a fish and a snake"

"Smith wants a spider and a horse"
```

the same shall not match if instead of "John" or "Smith" or "John Smith" there's nothing or any different word.
For example it *shall not* match if the sentence is something like:

```
"Jack wants a bird and a frog"
"wants a banana and a lemon"
```

Also the words in place of the animal names shall match as capturing groups.

I tried many combination but I'm not able to find the right "formula" because it matches also if there are different words or just empty at the beginning.
For example like this:

```
(John )?(Smith )?wants a ([a-z]*) and a ([a-z]*)
```

but it works also if I just input:

```
"wants a tiger and a lion"
```

by finding "tiger" and "lion" as groups, while in this case I *don't* want it to match as far as there's no (the right) name at the beginning.

Hope the explanation is clear enough.....
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `OR` between the fname and lname :

```
(?:John|Smith|John Smith) wants a ([a-z]*) and a ([a-z]*)
```